# Form Data is not Visible in Summernote After Fetching Data from DB

Tags: vue.js, laravel-8, summernote

I am using summernote editor. I facing an error when going on edit page.

**Form Field**

```
<div class="form-group col-12">
    <label>Service Content</label>
    <textarea name="content" id="summernote" class="form-control @error('content') is-invalid @enderror" rows="7" v-model="form.content">
    </textarea>

        @error('content')
            <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror

</div>
```

**Vue**

```
<script>
new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data() {
        return {
            form: {
                title: "{{ old('title', $page->title ?? '') }}",
                service_id: "{{ old('service_id', $page->service_id ?? '0') }}",
                keywords: "{!! old('keywords', $page->keywords ?? '') !!}",
                description: "{!! old('description', $page->description ?? '') !!}",
                content: "{!! old('content', $page->content ?? '') !!}",
                draft: "{{ old('draft', $page->draft ?? 'N') }}"
            },
            buttonText: "@if ($form !== 'add') Update @else Add @endif"
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

**Error in Console**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (at edit:506:25)

I am getting this error when I go on edit page.

[image]

Where i am doing wrong, can anyone please guide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my Issue by adding this `addslashes()`

```
content: "{!! old('content', addslashes($page->content) ?? '') !!}"
```